A test to check whether two sets of proportions are _not different_
Is there a test to check whether two small sets of proportions are significantly not different?
For example, consider the two sets of proportions
(0.2,0.3,0.25,0.35,0.19)
(0.31, 0.25, 0.21,0.17, 0.22) 
I want to demonstrate that the two sets are significantly not different. This means that the null hypothesis would have to be that they are different.
if one is interested in the source of the data, it is proportions of cell types for various samples. I want to show that after a treatment,  the distribution of the proportions of  the various cell types does not change.
The reason for  this choice of the null and the alternative is that the substantive claim I am interested in making is that no change has occurred between the two conditions. Failing to reject a null hypothesis of lack-of-change is not equivalent to accepting a hypothesis of lack-of-change, and it is the latter claim which is of interest.

Edit : In the example data, each value is a single sample. There is one cell-type with 5 samples, not five different cell-types (I have described it in a misleading way in the paragraph above).

You are looking for an "equivalence test", which usually boils down to two one-sided tests showing that the difference is neither greater nor smaller than some threshold $\Delta$. This would usually require a rather precise estimate for meaningfully small $\Delta$ and your sample isn't exactly large though.

Thanks. Also saw that this is possible for non-parametric
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881603/tost-for-non-parametric-data

@PBulls If you change your comment to an answer, I will accept that.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tost.


if one is interested in the source of the data, it is proportions of cell types for various samples. I want to show that after a treatment, the distribution of the proportions of the various cell types does not change.

The equivalence test mentioned by @PBulls seems to be an option. However, I surmise that the message above is best presented with a plot of cell types across conditions to visualize that treatment has virtually no effect. It maybe for example a beeswarm plot with median and some quantiles overlaid.
Personally, I would be convinced by a clear plot without p-values attached, but I would be suspicious about a statistics without plot, but of course you can add plot and p-values.

Yes, I agree that displaying the individual samples' proportions on a plot is necessary.

The answer to the question is indeed an equivalence test, as mentioned in comments, but definitively not on the data presented in the question. That data is 5 proportions of 5 different cell types, before and after a treatment. These 5 values are not even identically distributed (i.d.); the proportions come from possibly 5 different binomial distributions. And any test done using the 2 sets of 5 values would be a test of the mean (or the median, or equivalent parameter); if one proportion increased, but another decreased due to treatment, you will show identical means (medians), even though the individual proportions are significantly different.
You need to compare the 5 different pairs of proportions. And for that you need to compare the counts, not the proportions. You can run equivalence tests for all 5 (2 single sided tests, tests of 2 proportions -e.g. z test-, to prove that the difference is less than some $\delta$). Note that the $\delta$'s may be different for the different cell types (another reason/proof why the data, as presented in the question, is not usable). With a bit of luck, your counts of cells (both total, and of each type) are large enough that you would actually have some decent power.
Now there is the question of multiple comparisons. I would think you should use a multiple comparison correction (Sidak?) (you need 5 significant results, any one of which could be a false positive -due to "extreme" samples).
Edit, based on OP's clarifications
Based on OP's clarifications ("In the example data, each value is a single sample. There is one cell-type with 5 samples, not five different cell-types"), I need to change my answer.
So we have 2 samples, each with 5 observations (a sample is a collection of datapoints from a single population of interest; a single datapoint is an observation; see wiki for definitions).
The answer is still an equivalence test, but now between these 2 samples.
One option is to run a single 2 sample (Welch) t-test, and look at the CI for the difference of means. If that CI is within a clinically significant $\delta$, then you can conclude that the proportions are not clinically significantly different (the $\delta$ value is domain specific; is a 1% difference clinically significant, or a 5% or an 10%, or ?). But you have a very small sample size (5 observations), so it is unlikely that this would work (unless $\delta$ is very large; fwiw, a t-test gives a CI of [-6.2%,11.4%].
Another, most likely better option, is to look at the counts behind these 5 proportions (both count of the given type, and total cell count), and aggregate (i.e. sum) them over all 5 observations for each sample. You now have 4 counts, which you can enter into a contingency table. And you can solve using Fisher-exact, or $\chi^2$, or a z-test of 2 proportions. The hope here is that the counts will be large (hopefully in the 100's or 1000's?), and the CI should be much smaller. Fwiw, assuming you counted 100 cells for each observation (which would be on the low side...), the CI of the difference in proportions (using z-test) becomes [-2.7%,7.9%] (smaller than the previous one). If you counted 1000 cells for each observation, the CI is now [.09%,4.3%]; that may now make your case?\

Thank you; however, I have described the data in a confusing way in the OP (added a clarification now).

Almost all proportions are different.  Make it simple and compute an uncertainty/compatibility interval for the difference in two probabilities.
